# Woocommerce не отображаются отзывы/комментарии на странице товара

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Вот код, который выводит комментарии.
https://codeshare.io/anZVpj

```
<?
global $product;
?>
<div id="reviews" class="woocommerce-Reviews">
    <div id="comments">
  <h2 class="woocommerce-Reviews-title">
        <?php
        $count = $product->get_review_count();
        if ( $count && wc_review_ratings_enabled() ) {
            /* translators: 1: reviews count 2: product name */
            $reviews_title = sprintf( esc_html( _n( '%1$s review for %2$s', '%1$s reviews for %2$s', $count, 'woocommerce' ) ), esc_html( $count ), '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>' );
            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reviews_title', $reviews_title, $count, $product ); // WPCS: XSS ok.
        } else {
            esc_html_e( 'Reviews', 'woocommerce' );
        }
        ?>
    </h2> 

    <?php if ( !have_comments() ) : ?>
        <ol class="commentlist">
            <?php wp_list_comments( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_review_list_args', array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ) ) ); ?>
        </ol>

        <?php
        if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) :
            echo '<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">';
            paginate_comments_links(
                apply_filters(
                    'woocommerce_comment_pagination_args',
                    array(
                        'prev_text' => '&larr;',
                        'next_text' => '&rarr;',
                        'type'      => 'list',
                    )
                )
            );
            echo '</nav>';
        endif;
        ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <p class="woocommerce-noreviews"><?php esc_html_e( 'There are no reviews yet.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_review_rating_verification_required' ) === 'no' || wc_customer_bought_product( '', get_current_user_id(), $product->get_id() ) ) : ?>
    <div id="review_form_wrapper">
        <div id="review_form">
            <?php
            $commenter    = wp_get_current_commenter();
            $comment_form = array(
                /* translators: %s is product title */
                'title_reply'         => have_comments() ? esc_html__( 'Add a review', 'woocommerce' ) : sprintf( esc_html__( 'Be the first to review &ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'woocommerce' ), get_the_title() ),
                /* translators: %s is product title */
                'title_reply_to'      => esc_html__( 'Leave a Reply to %s', 'woocommerce' ),
                'title_reply_before'  => '<span id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">',
                'title_reply_after'   => '</span>',
                'comment_notes_after' => '',
                'label_submit'        => esc_html__( 'Submit', 'woocommerce' ),
                'logged_in_as'        => '',
                'comment_field'       => '',
            );

            $name_email_required = (bool) get_option( 'require_name_email', 1 );
            $fields              = array(
                'author' => array(
                    'label'    => __( 'Name', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'type'     => 'text',
                    'value'    => $commenter['comment_author'],
                    'required' => $name_email_required,
                ),
                'email'  => array(
                    'label'    => __( 'Email', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'type'     => 'email',
                    'value'    => $commenter['comment_author_email'],
                    'required' => $name_email_required,
                ),
            );

            $comment_form['fields'] = array();

            foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
                $field_html  = '<p class="comment-form-' . esc_attr( $key ) . '">';
                $field_html .= '<label for="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $field['label'] );

                if ( $field['required'] ) {
                    $field_html .= '&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span>';
                }

                $field_html .= '</label><input id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" type="' . esc_attr( $field['type'] ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $field['value'] ) . '" size="30" ' . ( $field['required'] ? 'required' : '' ) . ' /></p>';

                $comment_form['fields'][ $key ] = $field_html;
            }

            $account_page_url = wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' );
            if ( $account_page_url ) {
                /* translators: %s opening and closing link tags respectively */
                $comment_form['must_log_in'] = '<p class="must-log-in">' . sprintf( esc_html__( 'You must be %1$slogged in%2$s to post a review.', 'woocommerce' ), '<a href="' . esc_url( $account_page_url ) . '">', '</a>' ) . '</p>';
            }

            if ( wc_review_ratings_enabled() ) {
                $comment_form['comment_field'] = '<div class="comment-form-rating"><label for="rating">' . esc_html__( 'Your rating', 'woocommerce' ) . '</label><select name="rating" id="rating" required>
                    <option value="">' . esc_html__( 'Rate&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                    <option value="5">' . esc_html__( 'Perfect', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                    <option value="4">' . esc_html__( 'Good', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                    <option value="3">' . esc_html__( 'Average', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                    <option value="2">' . esc_html__( 'Not that bad', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                    <option value="1">' . esc_html__( 'Very poor', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                </select></div>';
            }

            $comment_form['comment_field'] .= '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . esc_html__( 'Your review', 'woocommerce' ) . '&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" required></textarea></p>';

            comment_form( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_review_comment_form_args', $comment_form ) );
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php else : ?>
    <p class="woocommerce-verification-required"><?php esc_html_e( 'Only logged in customers who have purchased this product may leave a review.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

Но вот так вот он выводит это на странице.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На странице редактирование товара, всё нормально.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можете увидеть в коде, у проверки if ( !have_comments() ) стоит восклицательный знак. Его поставил я, потому-что почему-то он возвращает false, хотя должен true.

Так-же для удобства вашего, вот ещё.
Как это выглядит у меня на сайте.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так это должно выглядеть.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На самом деле, на сайте у меня почему-то не было отзывов (сайт не мой, я дополняю).
В корневой папке темы, была папка woocommerce, в которой и были все нужные настройки.
Но там не было файла single-product-reviews.php, который по сути добавляет эти самые комментарии.
Я сначала попробовал взять этот файл из plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product-reviews.php и перекинуть в папку woocommerce в папке темы, не помогло. По этому я просто скопировал код и вставил на страницу товара.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение тут - https://web-answers.ru/php/rejting-woocommerce-ne-otobrazhaetsja-v-novoj.html
(Ответ который подсвечен зелёным, шаг 2).

Честно говоря, у меня не было некоторых моментов, как описал он, что сделал я:

Удалил get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

the_post() заменил на woocommerce_content()

Убрал while(have_posts() ): и соответственно endwhile

После этого заработало, но выглядело плохо, стилей не было. Видно реально, тема не поддерживает, по этому походу придётся самому оформлять.